# Threads and transactions : nested transactions not supported

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

I have two threads, A and B, and each of them inserts data into two different and unrelated tables.
However I am getting an `org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported`.

Here is the code doing the insertion for thread A :

```
    @Override
    public void setA(List<A> a) throws HibernateException {

        if (session == null) {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        }
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        try {
            int count = 0;
            for (A row : a) {
                session.save(row);

                if (count++ % 1000 == 0) {
                    session.flush();
                    session.clear();
                }
            }
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
                tx.rollback();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

The other method called by thread B is similar, only it is setting Bs instead of As...

How do I get these 2 threads to run concurrently without this exception ?

Comment: Since your method creates and ends the transaction within itself, each thread will have different transactions. It looks like before this method is invoked by the thread there already is a transaction associated with that thread. Probably you are already creating a transaction somewhere in the code before this piece runs.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `synchronized` block or `synchronized method` to perform above task.

Note, that Session is not a thread-safe object, but if you're sure it won't have problems with concurrency, what you need is just to use `TransactionSynchronizationUtils` to bind a session to the thread resources and then unbind it when desired

Comment: Do you have an example with TransactionSynchronizationUtils ? I am not familiar with this and didn't find much documentation.